# How to make parallel async queries in EF Core 3.0 with repository pattern?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, ef-core-3.0

I have repository like

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
  Task<EmployeeSettings> GetEmployeeSettings(int employeeId);
  Task<ICollection<DepartmentWorkPosition>> GetWorkPositions(int employeeId);
}
```

Constructor of repository (DbContext injection):

```
public EmployeeRepository(EmployeeDbContext dbContext)
{
  _dbContext = dbContext;
}
```

And call it in EF Core 2.0 like

```
var settingsTask = _employeeRepository
    .GetEmployeeSettings(employeeId.Value);

var workPositionsTask = _employeeRepository
    .GetWorkPositions(employeeId.Value);

await Task.WhenAll(settingsTask, workPositionsTask);

// do other things...
```

Problem:

With EF Core 3.0 there is InvalidOperationException: a second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed...

DbContext is registered in ConfigureServices like

```
services.AddDbContext<EmployeeDbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Tutorial says following:
Entity Framework Core does not support multiple parallel operations being run on the same DbContext instance.

But! How to use it with repositories in async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use it with repositories in async?

You can only have one simultaneous asynchronous request per repository. If you need to have more than one at a time, then you need more than one repository. This may require you to inject a repository *factory* into your types.

Comment: But why? What is wrong with two parallel queries that await data from server? Using different contexts implies performance hits, since contexts initialize some stuff when created - I guess pooling would solve this.

Comment: @MihaMarkic: I could be wrong, but I believe the reason is that a single db connection can only be used to stream one result set at a time. To stream another one, another connection would be necessary. There's a way to have multiple simultaneous result sets per connection but I don't think EF supports that.

Comment: That would I think as well. However, the old good ado.net practice is to open a connection, do what you have to do and dispose it immediately after - so it goes back to the pool. I wonder what decisions drove EF team to go with a single connection not being released at all (guessing).

Comment: The EF provider determines how connections are managed, and I believe all the big-name providers use connection pooling.

Comment: Multiple active result sets should handle more than one result at a time, my guess is the client side materialization of each result can't be multithreaded or queued for one at a time execution.... which is a shame since this worked in 2.2 and made it very easy to simultaneously have multiple potentially long running queries kicked off at the same time.

Comment: So another possible way is to configure DbContextPool to rent/release DbContext per query.

Answer (score 0):

Use factory and explicity instantiate context.

**Startup.cs**

```
//classical dbcontext registration
services.AddDbContext<TestDB>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("Test")));

//factory
//in case we want parallellize more queries at the same request, we can't use the same connection. So, because dbcontext is instantiate at request time this would  generate exception, so we need to use factory and explicit "using" to explicitly manage dbcontext lifetime
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDB>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Test"));
        services.AddSingleton(s => new Func<TestDB>(() => new TestDB(optionsBuilder.Options)));
```

**Service class**

```
public class TestService
{
    private readonly TestDB _testDb;
    private readonly Func<TestDB> _testDbfunct;

    public TestService(TestDB testDb, Func<TestDB> testDbfunct)
    {
        _testDb = testDb;
        _testDbfunct = testDbfunct;
    }

    //mixed classical request dbcontext and factory approaches
    public async Task<string> TestMultiple(int id, bool newConnection = false) //we need to add optional newConnection parameter and the end of other parameters
    {
        //use request connection (_testDb) if newconnection is false, otherwise instantiate a new connection using factory. null inside "using" means that "using" is not used
        //use newconnection = true if you want run parallel queries, so you need different connection for each one
        TestDB testDb = _testDb;
        using (newConnection ? testDb = _testDbfunct() : null)
        {
            return await (from t in testDb.Table where t.id == id select t.code).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        }
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```
    //instantiate dbcontext for each call, so we can parallellize
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMultiple()
    { 
        //test1 and test2 starts in parallel without test2 that need to wait the end of test1. For each one a Task in returned
        var test1 = _testService.TestMultiple(1,true);
        var test2 = _testService.TestMultiple(2,true);

        //wait test1 and test2 return
        string code1 = await test1;
        string code2 = await test2;

    }
    
    //use request dbcontext
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestClassic()
    {
        string code = await _testService.TestMultiple(3);

    }
```

NB: in new .net core 5 you can use buildin AddDbContextFactory instead of create a custom factory as in my example

Comment: No parallel code here. You await both test methods.

Comment: Hi. I await after they both start(the second to start don't wait the first that finish).             
Yon can also write: await Task.WhenAll(test1, test2) and you don't have exception because are used 2 different context;

Comment: I would LOVE to see a .Net 5.0 DBContextFactory solution. Can you add in an example of the newer code?

Answer (score -3):

just write:

```
var settings = await _employeeRepository.GetEmployeeSettings(employeeId.Value);
var workPositions = await _employeeRepository.GetWorkPositions(employeeId.Value);
```

Yeap. EF Core doesn't support multiple parallel operations being run on the same context instance. You should always wait for an operation to complete before beginning the next operation. This is typically done by using the await keyword on each async operation.
Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async

Comment: Downvoted: Question is not how to make these two queries run, but how to run them in parallel

Comment: there are no ways to use as parallel. please read my comment.

Comment: Queries can be run in parallel as long as they use different context instances, even if they are the same type of context.